# Using typeguard decorator: @typechecked in Python, whilst evading circular imports?

Tags: python, type-hinting, circular-dependency, typeguards

### Context

To prevent circular imports in Python when using type-hints, one can use [the following](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/13/python-type-hints-how-to-fix-circular-imports/) construct:

```py
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models import Book


class BookController:
    def __init__(self, book: "Book") -> None:
        self.book = book
```

Where the `if TYPE_CHECKING:` is only executed during type checking, and not during execution of the code.

### Issue

When one applies active function argument type verification, (based on the type hints of the arguments), `typeguard` throws the error:

> NameError: name 'Supported_experiment_settings' is not defined

### MWE I

```py
# models.py
from controllers import BookController

from typeguard import typechecked

class Book:
    
    @typechecked
    def get_controller(self, some_bookcontroller:BookController):
        return some_bookcontroller

some_book=Book()
BookController("somestring")
```

And:

```py
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from typeguard import typechecked
#from models import Book

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models import Book

class BookController:
    
    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, book: Book) -> None:
        self.book = book
```

Note the `#from models import Book` is commented out. Now if one runs:

```
python models.py
```

It throws the error:

> File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 13, in 
> BookController("somestring")
> ...
> NameError: name 'Book' is not defined. Did you mean: 'bool'?
> because the typechecking for `def __init__(self, book: Book) -> None:` does not know what the class Book is.

### MWE II

Then if one disables `@typechecked` in `controllers.py` with:

```
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from typeguard import typechecked

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models import Book

class BookController:
    
    #@typechecked
    def __init__(self, book: Book) -> None:
        self.book = book
```

it works. (But no typechecking).

### MWE III

Then if one re-enables typechecking, **and** includes the import of book, (with `from models import Book`) like:

```py
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from typeguard import typechecked
from models import Book

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models import Book

class BookController:
    
    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, book: Book) -> None:
        self.book = book
```

It throws the circular import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from controllers import BookController
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/controllers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import Book
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from controllers import BookController
ImportError: cannot import name 'BookController' from partially initialized module 'controllers' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/name/Documents/eg/controllers.py)
```

### Question

How can one evade this circular import whilst still allowing the `@typechecked` decorator to verify/access the `Book` import?

Is there an equivalent `TYPE_CHECKING` boolean for `typeguard`?

Comment: Side-note: The whole point of `from __future__ import annotations` is to allow you to annotate with names, not strings; the annotation can just be `def __init__(self, book: Book) -> None:` with `Book` unquoted.

Comment: Question: How is the circular import occurring? Can you show the [MCVE] that includes the other side of the circular import? Frequently the solution is to use normal `import modulename` imports instead of `from modulename import name` imports (the former delays resolving the contained names until time of use, which allows the circular import to work if the names from it aren't needed at top-level).

Comment: If you use `import model`, you'd have to change references to `Book` to `model.Book` (because you're no longer using the denamespacing form of import). The main question for whether it will work is whether `@typechecked` is trying to resolve the annotation at function definition time or at call time; if it does the former, this probably won't help (because the class/method defs and decoration is effectively done at top level, and one side or the other of the circular import won't be fully resolved when it happens), but if it's the latter, both imports can complete before the method is called.

Comment: And I just checked, it looks like resolving the annotations, not just checking them, is deferred to call time, so this should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that by using the denamespacing import form (`from x import y`) the contents of an imported module can't be resolved lazily, so one side or the other will require a name before the other module has finished importing (and therefore before it has defined the name).

The typical solution here is to use namespaced imports (`import x`) and qualify your uses (`x.y`) so that, assuming the names aren't needed to *define* your module, just when the functions within it are called, they can defer resolution to when they are needed and the circular aspect is not an issue.

Having checked the source code, `typechecked` is lazy and defers resolving annotations until the function in question is called, so it should be easy enough to fix this, changing your code to (inline comments indicating significant changes):

```
# models.py
from __future__ import annotations  # Ensure annotations evaluated lazily here as well,
                                    # so it works regardless of which module in the cycle
                                    # is imported first
import controllers  # Namespaced import

from typeguard import typechecked

class Book:
    @typechecked
    def get_controller(self, some_bookcontroller: controllers.BookController):  # Namespace qualified annotation
        return some_bookcontroller
```

And:

```
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typeguard import typechecked

import models  # Namespaced import

class BookController:
    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, book: models.Book) -> None:  # Namespace qualified annotation
        self.book = book
```

The code from `models.py` that does:

```
some_book=Book()
BookController("somestring")
```

should be moved from `models` to some other module that imports those names from the two modules with circular dependencies to make the code completely robust. This is because, being at top-level, depending on which of the cyclicly defined modules got imported first (the problem occurs with `models.py` here), it would be unable to resolve the name from `controllers`, even if the name is namespace-qualified (because it would be trying to use it before `models` finished being defined, and when the import of `controllers` pauses to wait on `models` to finish being defined, it hasn't defined the rest of its contents, and therefore the code that runs on import in `models` can't resolve the names from `controllers`).

If it's in some other module importing from `models` and `controllers`, both of those imports will resolve by the time the subsequent code is run (assuming neither of them import this hypothetical `module3` themselves), so it works either way (using namespaced or denamespaced imports).

---

If you're curious how circular imports work in Python, there's a complete explanation on [What happens when using mutual or circular (cyclic) imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/364696), but the short version is that, the very first time a module is imported in an entire program, Python puts an empty module object in the `sys.modules` cache, then runs the code within the module to populate the cached module object. The *second* time a module is imported, including when it's imported by a module that imports the original module cyclically, Python just binds the cached module object and does nothing else, even if the cached module object isn't populated yet.

This means that when an import in progress at the top of the stack (module `B`) tries to import a module that is already in progress below it on the stack (module `A`), module `B` gets the incompletely initialized module from the cache (because `A` was already in the process of being imported). If defining the contents of `B` relies on any component of `A` that was not defined before `A` tried to import `B`, it won't exist on the cached (and mostly empty) `A` module. But so long as all such reference to `A` in `B` are confined to functions that aren't called during definition time, or are used in annotations that `from __future__ import annotations` converts to string-based annotations and nothing tries to resolve them during the import process, this works fine. `B` finishes being defined without trying to use any elements from `A`, and when `A`'s definition resumes, a complete `B` module exists for it to load from.

The problem occurs when the module in a cycle imported second (`B` in this case) tries to use a component of the module imported first (`A`) that isn't defined until after `A` finishes importing `B` (usually pretty early on in `A`, so almost nothing in `A` is defined). `from A import spam` requires resolving `A.spam` immediately, so it's going to break. `import A`, and using `A.spam` at top level (as you did with `controllers.BookController` in your original code) also breaks things.

Your use case was even nastier, because in fact, `python models.py`, there were secretly *three* modules involved:

1. `__main__` (which is the pseudoname given to the top level script, so the code is whatever is in `models.py`, but it is not the same thing as the `models` module for import/cache purposes), which imports...
2. `controllers`, which in turn imports...
3. `models`, which then cyclically imports `controllers`

This makes things uglier, because despite thinking you imported `models` first, you actually imported `controllers` before `models`, and the code in `models.py` is executed twice, once for the script itself as `__main__`, and once for the import as `models`. There are two unrelated `Book` classes (which can cause type-checking issues), and that top-level code in `models.py` was executed twice (creating two instances of `BookController`, and one instance each of the two unrelated but identical definitions of `Book`).

The solution is:

1. Ensure *both* sides of the circular import use plain namespaced imports (`import A`/`import B`) and *neither* tries to access any component of the other at top-level (including at class definition level when the class is at top level), nor do they try to call any methods/functions/constructors from top-level that would indirectly access another component. Technically speaking, you *could* make a working use case without both of them being so careful, but it would be incredibly brittle; whichever module took an eager dependency on the other must be imported first, and in practice, you don't want to assume that one module is *always* imported first (you could force it in a package structure that includes a `__init__.py`, but that breaks implicit namespace packages, and it's still brittle from a maintainer's point of view, even if it's safe from an API consumer point of view), so it's best to do the cautious thing on both sides.
2. Never involve a module that will be invoked as a script (with `python modulename.py` or `python -mmodulename`) in a circular import scenario. Ideally never write a module that will be used as both script and imported module in the same run of the program (either it's the main script and no one else imports it, or it's imported as a module with some other script serving as main). If a module is both run as the top-level script *and* imported elsewhere, weird stuff happens.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by @ShadowRanger worked. importing the module and only calling book in the typing, evaded the circular import (only when calling `python controllers.py` (which also runs `models.py`), though not when calling `python models.py`, (see Limitations)).

### MWE

```py
# models.py
import controllers

from typeguard import typechecked

class Book:
    
    @typechecked
    def get_controller(self, some_bookcontroller:controllers.BookController):
        return some_bookcontroller

some_book=Book()

controllers.BookController(some_book)
#controllers.BookController("somestring")
```

```py
# controllers.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from typeguard import typechecked
import models

class BookController:
    
    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, book: models.Book) -> None:
        self.book = book
```

This can be ran with:

```
python controllers.py
```

and it throws a `circular import error` with:

```
python models.py
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    import controllers
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/controllers.py", line 5, in <module>
    import models
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Book:
  File "/home/name/Documents/eg/models.py", line 9, in Book
    def get_controller(self, some_bookcontroller:controllers.BookController):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'controllers' has no attribute 'BookController' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

One can notice that Typeguard throws an error when a string is passed into `BookController()` instead of a `Book()`, meaning it correctly performs type checking.

### Limitations

One should then think to design the code such that one does not need to call the `models.py`.

Comment: FYI, I posted my own answer with this information, the explanation, and even a note (written before you discovered the problem) explaining why the top-level use of `some_book=Book()` and `controllers.BookController(some_book)` within `models.py` leaves the code fragile, and how to make it a robust.