# Python's isinstance method result is unexpected for subclass instance

Tags: python, subclass, program-entry-point, isinstance

Defining two classes (a base "ClassA" and a subclass "ClassB" in two separate files), gives unexpected results when using Python's isinstance method. Output appears to be impacted by the module name (namespace?) used while running (__main__). This behavior appears on both Python 3.8.5 and 3.10.4.

File ClassA.py contains:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        class_name = type(self).__name__
        return f"{class_name} WITH id: {self.id}"

def main():
    from ClassB import ClassB
    id = 42
    for i, instance in enumerate([ClassA(id), ClassB(id)]):
        label = f"{type(instance).__name__}:"
        print("#" * 50)
        print(f"{label}   type: {type(instance)}")
        label = " " * len(label)  # Convert label to appropriate number of spaces
        is_a = isinstance(instance, ClassA)
        is_b = isinstance(instance, ClassB)
        print(f"{label} is_a/b: {is_a}/{is_b}")
        print(f"{label}    str: {instance}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

File ClassB.py contains:

```
from ClassA import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__(id)
        self.id *= -1
```

File main.py contains:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from ClassA import main
    main()
```

The output from running ClassA.py gives:

```
01: ##################################################
02: ClassA:   type: <class '__main__.ClassA'>
03:         is_a/b: True/False
04:            str: ClassA WITH id: 42
05: ##################################################
06: ClassB:   type: <class 'ClassB.ClassB'>
07:         is_a/b: False/True
08:            str: ClassB WITH id: -42
```

While the output from running main.py (which calls ClassA.main) gives:

```
01: ##################################################
02: ClassA:   type: <class 'ClassA.ClassA'>
03:         is_a/b: True/False
04:            str: ClassA WITH id: 42
05: ##################################################
06: ClassB:   type: <class 'ClassB.ClassB'>
07:         is_a/b: True/True
08:            str: ClassB WITH id: -42
```

Notice how the type of the ClassA instance changes (on Lines 02) from '__main__.ClassA' (when run from ClassA.py) to 'ClassA.ClassA' (when run from main.py). Similarly, the isinstance type checks for ClassA and ClassB (on Lines 07) change from 'False/True' (unexpected) to 'True/True' (desired, expected).

Any comments/suggestions/explanations would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @buran: That's not a good duplicate target; the issue here is the weirdness involved with circular imports where the `__main__` script is part of the cycle. [Using typeguard decorator: @typechecked in Python, whilst evading circular imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74308059/364696) is a kinda-sorta duplicate (in that the problem is similar, and the solution and explanation are the same), but I'm not confident enough of that to invoke my dupehammer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have here is due to `ClassA` being defined in your main script, and you having circular imports. You actually have *three* modules involved in your script, not two:

1. The main script, under the name `__main__` (defines `__main__.ClassA`), which imports...
2. `ClassB` (defines `ClassB.ClassB`) which imports...
3. `ClassA` (defines `ClassA.ClassA` that is defined identically to `__main__.ClassA`, but is a unique and independent class) a completely separate copy of the main script, but imported independently under a different name so `__main__` related behaviors don't trigger

Importantly, `ClassB.ClassB` is inheriting from `ClassA.ClassA`, but `main` is type-checking against `__main__.ClassA`, a completely unrelated class.

[I've gone over why this doesn't work as expected before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74376396/364696) (and [again in another context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890887/364696)), so I'll simplify the answer here for your specific case to: **Don't involve `__main__` in any circular imports**. It can import whatever it likes, but it should not have anything else importing from it. In this case, your `main.py` refactoring is enough to fix the issue (by ensuring there is only one version of class `ClassA`, `ClassA.ClassA`). It does have a circular import dependency, which is always a little weird (I'd recommend moving the function `main` to `main.py` to avoid that), but since you're deferring one of the imports it's safe enough.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being totally clear in my explanation but running main.py works __exactly__ as I would expect. Additionally, I don't think I have any problems with circular imports; those would raise exceptions causing an exit, correct? I agree with your statements about the (confusing) number of modules but I am confused about why (when running ClassA.py) the class \_\_main\_\_.ClassA is not __equivalent__ to ClassA.ClassA. If that were the case (for the artificial \_\_main\_\_ module) then I would be all fat, dumb, and happy.

Comment: your linked answer went a bit over my head. However, I think the solution you mentioned in your last paragraph for this question is essentially what I implemented in the separate file "main.py", correct? I achieved it by calling ClassA's "main" but I also could have moved/copied ClassA's "main" to "main.py" and added imports for ClassA/ClassB exactly as you were suggesting. I probably should have directly asked: "Why do classes in a module lose capabilities when they are temporarily run as the \_\_main\_\_ module?"

Comment: @skuzmo: You have what *would* be a circular import, if not for the fact that `__main__.ClassA` and `ClassA.ClassA` are unrelated. `__main__` imports module `ClassB`, which in turn imports module `ClassA`, and it's only because `__main__` is *not* module `ClassA` that no circular import occurs. On rereading, yes, what you did with a minimal separate `main.py` was enough to fix things (because now the class `ClassA` is unique, there aren't two versions). With `main.py` you *do* have a circular import, but you've handled it safely enough so you don't fail because of it.

Comment: @skuzmo: On "Why is `__main__.ClassA` not equivalent to `ClassA.ClassA`?": Because `ClassA.py` gets imported and cached *twice*, once under the name `__main__` (so it can do main script behaviors), and once under the name `ClassA` (as an imported module). The import process is assumed to differ between the two, so importing it only once would be wrong (what if certain things are defined differently when it's `__main__` vs. `ClassA`?). It's imported twice because the main script *must* be imported with the weird name so it knows to do scripty things.

Comment: Imports are cached, but if you check `sys.modules`, you'll see it actually got cached twice, under each name, because it was read, parsed, compiled, and run twice, one ends up stored as `sys.modules['__main__']`, the other as `sys.modules['ClassA']`, and if you compare the class `ClassA` in each, you'll see it's not the same thing (`sys.modules['__main__'].ClassA is sys.modules['ClassA'].ClassA` will be `False`).

Comment: It helps to keep the distinction between *files* and *modules* clear. When you execute `ClassA.py` as a script, the *file* `ClassA.py` is used to create one module (named `__main__`) immediately, and later (via the `ClassB` modules) the same file is used to create a distinct module named `ClassA`. One file, used to create two modules. When you execute `main.py`, `ClassA.py` is only used to create one module named `ClassA`.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, it's not Java, naming the module and the class the same thing (especially in a complicated circular dependency case like this) is unnecessary, and making things more confusing.